# What is meant by an Orthogonal $1$-form

Tags: differential-geometry, definition, fiber-bundles, principal-bundles, holonomy

In [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1206.3170.pdf) article, titled *Holonomy Groups in Riemannian Geometry*, on pg 37, the following line appears (before equation 2.5.3)

> Let $\theta$ be a horizontal, orthogonal $1$-form on $\mathcal F_{GL}$

Here $\mathcal F_{GL}$ denotes the frame bundle of a smooth manifold $M$.

I know what a horizontal bundle of a fiber bundle means, and I know what a connection $1$-form on a principal bundle means. But I am unable to see what is meant by a "horizontal orthogonal $1$-form". Can somebody please explain what this means?

Comment: Does it means orthogonal ($o(n)$)-valued?